# Joining three tables in excel sql

Tags: sql, excel

I am trying to join three tables in one query

For the two tables I am using LEFT JOIN

```
FROM (`\\a\WEZ.xlsx`.`Sheet1$` `Sheet1$` 
LEFT JOIN `\\a\ZC02.xlsx`.`Sheet1$` `B` ON `Sheet1$`.`Material`=`B`.`Material Number`)
```

And I want add another one

```
`\\a\master.xlsx`.`Sheet1$` `C`
```

Thank you very much for every Response!

Comment: What are the columns in `master.xlsx`?

Comment: in wez it is `MAT_ABL` and in Master it is `MAT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for:

```
FROM `\\a\WEZ.xlsx`.`Sheet1$` `Sheet1$` 
LEFT JOIN `\\a\ZC02.xlsx`.`Sheet1$` `B` ON `Sheet1$`.`Material`=`B`.`Material Number`
LEFT JOIN `\\a\master.xlsx`.`Sheet1$` `C` ON `Sheet1$`.`MAT`=`C`.`MAT_ABL`
```